# Popstate not working on some of the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using code as below:

```
if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
    window.history.pushState('forward', null, './#forward');
    $(window).on('popstate', function () {
        window.location.href = "https://www.google.com/";   
    });
}
```

I want to add #forward in URL using "Push state" then if the user clicks on the browser back button I want to redirect to another link.

Working : It is working in chrome but not working with "CANARY" search engine.
Please help me to figure out this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Facing the same issue i am giving a try using history.js